# Bloquear scroll vertical del body cuando un modal está activo

Tags: javascript, css, modal, scroll, overflow

Hola que tal tengo un modal con la clase de css show, la cual se mostrará al hacer click en un botón (.btn_menu), estoy intentando por medio de JS que cuando esta clase esté activa, el body tenga un `overflow:hidden`, y al desactivarla el body pasará a tener un `overflow: scroll`, (básicamente porque no sé con JS eliminar la propiedad que anteriormente le he dado).
Pasa que al hacer click consigo bloquear el scroll del body, pero al quitar el modal, se **sigue manteniendo** el `overflow:hidden`, lo que permanentemente bloquea la web de poder hacer scroll.

He probado a darle la condición con un if else, estilo:

```
 addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    const btn_menu = document.querySelector('.btn_menu');
    const btn_sections = document.querySelectorAll('.menu_items li a')
    const menu_items = document.querySelector('.menu_items');
    const icon = document.querySelector('.btn_menu i');
    if(btn_menu){
        btn_menu.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            
            menu_items.classList.toggle('show');
            icon.classList.toggle('fa-x');
            if (menu_items.classList.contains('show')){
                document.body.style.overflow='hidden';
            }
            else{
                document.body.style.overflow='scroll';
            }
        }); 
    }
    btn_sections.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            document.getElementById(element.ariaValueText).scrollIntoView();
            menu_items.classList.remove('show');
            icon.classList.toggle('fa-x');

        })
    })
    
    
})
```

Me parece raro que no termine de funcionar con este código.

Answer (score 0):

si pruebas en vez de `overflow = 'scroll'` lo dejas en auto `overflow = 'auto'`

si no ya crear una clase y agregarla y quitarla con la propiedad

```
.scroll{ 
  //overflow-y: scroll; 
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```